# how do I check the current coordinates of a moving UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, core-animation, coordinates

I have a UIImageView that is undergoing a simple translation animation, and I am trying to get the coordinates of the view while it is moving via the imageview.frame.origin.x property. However, it is giving me the coordinates that the imageview will be at after the animation. Is there any way to get the current coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to check the coordinates of the presenationLayer. You can read a detailed description about it in [my blog post about tapping moving layers](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/21228285860/hit-testing-animating-layers).